# Gulp inject HTML snippets into named targets

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

we're handling low level html markup as npm modules where one could specify via comment, the name of a modules whose supporting html would be injected at that location. A module contains the html, supporting SCSS and vanilla JS. From a SCSS & JS standpoint everything is buttoned up. The moment the module is installed, the SCSS is compiled, concatenated & appended to a core CSS file and then minified. The JS treatment is very similar.

Where I'm getting very hung up on is how to treat the html snippets. Here is what I've got, which works but this isn't dynamic in any way.

```
gulp.task('inject-atoms', function () {
gulp.src('./index.html')
  .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./node_modules/my-module-name/my-module-name.html']), {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:html -->',
    transform: function (filePath, file) {
      return file.contents.toString('utf8')
    }
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

What I'd like to be able do (within the target index.html file) is specify module names whose html snippets get injected. So something like:

```
<!-- inject:my-module-ABC --!>
<!-- inject:my-module-XYC --!>
```

The only requirement being that the modules have been installed prior to trying to inject their snippets. So the gulp task would need to sweep through the index file and for each inject comment, go fetch that module's html snippet and inject it in.

Any tips on helping me move in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#injecting-files-contents-based-on-file-path what you want?  Injecting file contents based on file path section

Comment: I noticed that but that would involve tracking down the path for each snippet which defeats the purpose because at the point where a developer is having to write the path out, they could just dig into the module dir and copy and paste the code wherever they wanted it. I was hoping to be able to just pass in like inject:module-name-blah and not have to worry about paths in the injection spot all together.

Comment: I have never used it but I think you put the path into the inject tag:  <!-- inject:path/to/my-module-ABC.html --!> so essentially what you were thinking of doing anyhow.  And then gulp-inject uses that path for that tag.